# Converted from SqlDataSource to ObjectDataSource, causing grief

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0, objectdatasource

I have created a data access layer in my web app which uses ObjectDataSource instead of SqlDataSource. I have a FormView to update some data in my database. In my old asp.net code I had something like:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsTradeDetails" runat="server" 
 ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ForexDB %>" 
 SelectCommand="usp_GetTrade" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
 UpdateCommand="usp_UpdateTrade" UpdateCommandType="StoredProcedure" 
 <SelectParameters>
  <asp:ControlParameter Name="tradeId" ControlID="grdTrades" PropertyName="SelectedDataKey.Value" />            
 </SelectParameters>
 <UpdateParameters>
  <asp:ControlParameter Name="tradeId" ControlId="frmTrade" PropertyName="SelectedValue"  />
 </UpdateParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Which worked fine. I have replaced the SqlDataSource with this:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource
 id="srcTrade" 
 TypeName="DatabaseComponent.DBUtil" 
 SelectMethod="GetTrade"
 UpdateMethod="UpdateTrade"
 runat="server">
 <SelectParameters>
  <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="tradeId" QueryStringField="tradeId" />               
 </SelectParameters>
 <UpdateParameters>
  <asp:ControlParameter Name="tradeId" ControlId="frmTrade" PropertyName="SelectedValue"  />
 </UpdateParameters>
</asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

But now I get this error when I click the Update button in my FormView:

> Exception Details:
>   System.InvalidOperationException:
>   ObjectDataSource 'srcTrade' could not
>   find a non-generic method
>   'UpdateTrade' that has parameters:
>   symbol, pctAccountRisked,
>   tradeSetupId, lotsPerUnit,
>   initialStopPrice, tfCode, MAEPips,
>   MFEPips, tradeGrade, executionGrade,
>   tradeTypeId, comment, tradeId.

In my DBUtil class I have this for UpdateTrade:

```
public void UpdateTrade(
 int tradeId, 
 string symbol, 
 decimal pctAccountRisked, 
 string tradeSetupId, 
 decimal lotsPerUnit, 
 decimal initialStopPrice, 
 string tfCode, 
 int MAEPips, 
 int MFEPips, 
 int tradeGrade, 
 int executionGrade, 
 string comment)
{
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_UpdateTrade");
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tradeId", tradeId);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@symbol", symbol);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pctAccountRisked", pctAccountRisked);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tradeSetupId", tradeSetupId);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lotsPerUnit", lotsPerUnit);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@initialStopPrice", initialStopPrice);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tfCode", tfCode);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MAEPips", MAEPips);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MFEPips", MFEPips);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tradeGrade", tradeGrade);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@executionGrade", executionGrade);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@comment", comment);
 UpdateTable(cmd, "trade");
}
```

and this for GetTrade:

```
public DataTable GetTrade(int tradeId)
{
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_GetTrade");
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tradeId", tradeId);
 return FillDataTable(cmd, "trade");
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi your UpdateTrade method and the passing parameters from your datasource are missmatching. please recheck them

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I've just checked the parameters. I'm not really sure what you mean, but what i did was check that the columns returned by GetTrade exist in UpdateTrade. There are some extra columns returned by GetTrade that don't exist in UpdateTrade, but that's what I want. What else could I check? Do I need to list every Update parameter in UpdateTrade? When using a SqlDataSource I didn't need to do that, I just added the primary key (tradeId) as the only parameter to UpdateTrade.

Comment: yes, you need to have all the parameters to the UpdateTrade method as UpdateParameters (or have to add them in the code-behind before the update fires).